# JPA: Time taken for reading hierarchy

Tags: jpa

I am using JPA to fetch an entity from database. Entity has parent-child relatioship, and I want to fetch entire hierarchy. So I fetch all root nodes(entities having no parent) and then I iterate these nodes recursively to fetch whole of hierarchy.

All nodes are fetched, but it is taking almost 12+ minutes. There are total 5500 rows in table.

I want to know whether it is a good performance or should I improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading a full table if I understand correctly. You just happen to fetch the roots and dive deep in the hierarchy with a visitor to trigger initialization of associations. This will generate a lot of individual select statements to fetch only parts of the hierarchy and it will multiply the latency from your app to the database by the number of statements issued.

If that's the case, you could just as well fetch the whole table in one select `LEFT JOIN FETCH`-ing the `OneToMany` association from the parent to the children. This way, you'll have the whole hierarchy loaded in just one round-trip with the database.

Supposing `HierarchyElement` is your entity class, `HierarchyElement.children` is the collection to an element's children `HierarchyElement.parent` being the reference to the parent, the following JPA query

```
select he from HierarchyElement he where he.parent is null
```

folowed by a visitor iterating over the elements and recursively initializing the `HierarchyElement.children` collections will be orders of magnitude slower than

```
select he from HierarchyElement he left join fetch he.children
```

With this latter query you'll have all your `HierarchyElement` loaded with their `HierarchyElement.children` collections all initialized. And since you're loading the whole table, you'll have all possible `HierarchyElement.parent` relations correctly pointing to the proper entity, even if the `parent` association is marked as `LAZY`. This works, because all entities will be in the first cache when the JPA provider builds the entities for you and the JPA provider will know which entity to wire in.

With the above, you can easily go through all the fetched elements and take only those where the parent is null which are the hierarchy roots.

Comment: Thanks.Would try with this idea.

Comment: Thanks Nandor. I made changes as per your suggestions, and performance has improved drastically.

Comment: May I ask what is the time required to fetch the records with this method? Just to compare with the original ~12 minutes.

Comment: it took around 3-4 seconds.

Comment: That's kind of an improvement, isn't it?! :)